# How to simulate TV/monitor looks using modern browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

How they achieved this effect? http://youxithemes.com/live_previews/hydrogen/light/index.html

The slider background use this style:

```
element.style {
background-image: url(http://youxithemes.com/live_previews/hydrogen/light/demo/img/splash-bg.jpg);
background-position: 50% 0px;
}
```

But i have no idea how they apply that *monitor look* effect on the background. Is css or js? please point me in the right direction, a code example will be also appreciated!

Comment: It's a simple semitransparent PNG overlay... There is no CSS or JS or code example to provide you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is contained in the `background-image` line of `.site-splash .overlay` as a base64 encoded png.

```
.site-splash .overlay {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUAQMAAAC3R49OAAAABlBMV…AAAnRSTlMAmf9A5tgAAAARSURBVAjXY1i1agEDEFCLBgA1MROJWXE8mAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made something like this for a client before. You can see it live at `<br>`[LIVE DEMO](http://www.triscari.com/web3.php). `<br>`

I extracted the code from my files. I assume you will be able to work with this if you apply yourself

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/lotusms/gR7R3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to use js for this, here is a pute javascript solution:

**HTML**

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test {
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:block;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    line-height:4px;
    font-size:10px
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
for (var i=0; i<6000; i++) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML  = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML+". ";  
}
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HbYHP/)**

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the Vegas full screen image plugin.
— http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/

I think you can choose different overlay types, including the one you linked up.

Comment: OP didn't ask specifically for the slider used, but the method the slider was implemented as if it was being shown inside a laptop or PC monitor

Comment: He asked how it was achieved, and I just pointed one fast way of doing it without needing to create a file in photoshop etc. But yeah, I understand what you mean. New to stackoverflow!